# Looping through track keys and jumping to the appropriate part of the loop structure

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop

#### My [repl](https://repl.it/@dunwana/FrontAttentiveParameter)

(Various JSON files for various language use cases.)

```
import json

# v = "64457.json" #jp
# v = "35777.json" #en, jp, ro
v = "66622.json" #ge, jp, ro
# v = "50900k.json" #ko
# v = "25364c.json" #ch, en

with open(v) as f:
    data = json.load(f)

track_list = data['discs'][0]['tracks']
langs = ('German', 'French' , 'Korean', 'Chinese')

for x, track in enumerate(track_list):
  for i in track['names']:
    print i, len(track["names"].keys())
    if i not in langs:
      print "NOT I"
      if len(track["names"].keys()) == 3 and i in ('Romaji', 'Japanese', 'English'):
        d = track["names"]["Romaji"]
        s = track["names"]["Japanese"]
        y = track["names"]["English"]
        print '-', x+1, y, d, s
        break
    elif len(track["names"].keys()) == 3 and i in langs and i in ('Romaji', 'Japanese'):
        d = track["names"]["Romaji"]
        s = track["names"]["Japanese"]
        y = track["names"][i]
        print '@', x+1, y, d, s
        break
    elif len(track["names"].keys()) == 2 and i in langs:
      y = track["names"][i]
      e = track["names"]["English"]
      print '+', x+1, y, e
      break
  else:
    print '~', x+1, track["names"].values()[0]
```

#### Error Printed

```
German 3
Japanese 3
NOT I
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 25, in <module>
    y = track["names"]["English"]
KeyError: 'English'
```

#### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to loop through each of the keys in `track['names']`. Once it hits a key that is also in the `langs` tuple, I want it to stop and go to the corresponding section in the `if` section. If it's not in the `langs` tuple, it should output what info it does have, especially if the keys are Eng, Rom, *and* Jpn. I think all the looping is confusing me.

Comment: what should the "corresponding" "if section" for a key in the langs tuple do? What is the operation you want to execute for those? What I understand of it now is: when you find something in the langs tuple, based on the number of languages present, you want to print a special symbol and then print ALL the other languages out, whether or not they're in the langs tuple. Is that correct?

Comment: how do you determine whether to print -, @, +, or ~? I'm working on fixing the code for you, but need to understand that before I can.

Comment: @HarshitaGupta Those symbols basically just let me know at a glance which part of the loop was entered. That's all. They're random symbols.

Comment: cool, can you also tell me the answer to my first question?

Comment: @HarshitaGupta For example, if the `track['names'].key()` is German (or Chinese or Korean, etc), I want it to enter the if statement where `langs` is a condition and then if it has another `track['names'].key()` of English and Romaji AND the number of keys is 3, then it will enter the specific `if` mentioning all 3 conditions. If `track['names'].key()`, is not in `langs` and has the keys Japanese, English, and Romaji, then it will enter that `if` and output those track names. Sorry if I didn't explain it well enough.

Comment: check out the answer below: I cleaned your code up and got you started on the conditionals.

Comment: how did that work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't completely understand which conditions you care about, but here's code that you can modify to meet your needs. You had too many for loops, so I took one out and then set up some boolean variables that you can use.

```
track_list = data['discs'][0]['tracks']
langs = ('German', 'French' , 'Korean', 'Chinese')

for x, track in enumerate(track_list):
  # below variable is an int with the number of names the track has
  num_names = len(track["names"].keys())
  # below variable is true if one of the track's names is in a lang language
  name_in_lang_bool = any([lang in langs for lang in track["names"].keys()])
  # below variable is true if one of the track's names is in Romaji or English
  name_english_romaji_bool = any([lang in ("English", "Romaji") for lang in track["names"].keys()])

  # you can combine these variables for various conditionals like so: 
  if name_in_lang_bool and num_names == 3 and name_english_romaji_bool:
    print "this track has three names, one of them is in langs, and one of them is either English OR Romaji"

    # this is how you print out all the track's names: 
    for (language, name) in track["names"].iteritems():
      print "name in", language, "is", name

  # here's another example condition 
  elif name_in_lang_bool and num_names == 2:
    print "this track has two names, one of them is in langs"
    for (language, name) in track["names"].iteritems():
      print "name in", language, "is", name
```

Comment: Wow, this looks great! I'm very bad at loops, but you've given me a lot to study. I changed some things around and now it works with all the use cases I needed. Here is the "final" [result](https://repl.it/@dunwana/AdequateModestAlgorithms). I'm gonna keep trying to optimize it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it might help to see a different approach to the problem altogether:

- You have keys in `track["names"]` (I'm assuming this is a dictionary)
- You then want

  - the keys belonging to `langs`, and
  - the keys not belonging to `langs`

Consider this:

```
keys_in_langs = filter(lambda key: key in langs, track["names"].keys())
vice_versa = filter(lambda key: key not in langs, track["names"].keys())
```

The `filter` applies the lambda function to each item in `keys`, returning the list for which that anonymous function returns true. Is this what you need?

Comment: I would appreciate knowing why this got downvoted. I even asked to make sure it's what the OP was looking for---I explicitly answered their question without writing their code for them.